# ConnectionResetError (104, 'Connection reset by peer) in kserve?

Tags: istio, huggingface-transformers, knative, knative-serving, kubeflow-kserve

I have A Hugging face model https://huggingface.co/TahaDouaji/detr-doc-table-detection in Torch serve it is working fine when I deployed it in locally. I tried to deploy the model in kserve as DockerImage. Pods are running fine without any error i tried to CURL request the model from the model pod, I'm getting the error like "ConnectionResetError (104, 'Connection reset by peer)". Here is my Transformerhandler.py file

```
import os
import json
import logging
from PIL import Image
import io
import torch
from transformers import DetrForObjectDetection
from ts.torch_handler.base_handler  import BaseHandler
from detectron2.structures import Boxes, ImageList, Instances, BitMasks, PolygonMasks
from detectron2.modeling import META_ARCH_REGISTRY, build_backbone, detector_postprocess
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer, VisImage
from detectron2.layers import batched_nms
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torch.nn.functional
import numpy as np
import base64

def box_cxcywh_to_xyxy(x):
   x_c, y_c, w, h = x.unbind(-1)
   b = [(x_c - 0.5 * w), (y_c - 0.5 * h),
        (x_c + 0.5 * w), (y_c + 0.5 * h)]
   return torch.stack(b, dim=-1)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

ipex_enabled = False
if os.environ.get("TS_IPEX_ENABLE", "false") == "true":
   try:
       import intel_extension_for_pytorch as ipex

       ipex_enabled = True
   except ImportError as error:
       logger.warning(
           "IPEX is enabled but intel-extension-for-pytorch is not installed. Proceeding without IPEX."
       )

class TransformersDetrHandler(BaseHandler):
   """
   The handler takes an input string and returns the classification text
   based on the serialized transformers checkpoint.
   """
   def __init__(self):
       super(TransformersDetrHandler, self).__init__()
       self.initialized = False
       self.pixel_mean = np.asarray([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
       self.pixel_std = np.asarray([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
       self.normalizer = lambda x: (x - self.pixel_mean) / self.pixel_std
       self.test_nms_thresh = 0.6
       self.score_thresh = 0.7
       self.mask_on = False

       self.transform = T.Compose([
           T.Resize(800),
           T.ToTensor(),
           T.Normalize(self.pixel_mean, self.pixel_std)
       ])

   @torch.no_grad()
   def initialize(self, ctx):
       """ Loads the model.pt file and initializes the model object.
       Instantiates Tokenizer for preprocessor to use
       Loads labels to name mapping file for post-processing inference response
       """
       self.manifest = ctx.manifest
       logger.debug(f"manifest => {self.manifest} =====================")

       properties = ctx.system_properties
       logger.debug(f"properties => {properties} =====================")

       model_dir = properties.get("model_dir")
       self.device = torch.device("cuda:" + str(properties.get("gpu_id")) if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

       # Read model serialize/pt file
       serialized_file = self.manifest["model"]["serializedFile"]
       model_pt_path = os.path.join(model_dir, serialized_file)
       if not os.path.isfile(model_pt_path):
           raise RuntimeError("Missing the model.pt or pytorch_model.bin file")

       # Load model
       self.model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(model_dir)

       if ipex_enabled:
           self.model = self.model.to(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
           self.model = ipex.optimize(self.model)
       else:
           self.model.to(self.device)

       self.model.eval()
       logger.debug('Transformer model from path {0} loaded successfully'.format(model_dir))

       # Read the mapping file, index to object name
       mapping_file_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "index_to_name.json")

       if os.path.isfile(mapping_file_path):
           with open(mapping_file_path) as f:
               self.mapping = json.load(f)
               logger.debug(f'Label => {self.mapping}')
       else:
           logger.warning('Missing the index_to_name.json file. Inference output will not include class name.')

       self.initialized = True

   def preprocess(self, data):
       images = []
       self.image_sizes = []
       for row in data:
           # Read image from body and data
           image = row.get("data") or row.get("body")


           # Parse base64 to image to bytes
           if isinstance(image, str):
               # if the image is a string of bytesarray.
               image = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(image.split(',')[1])

           if isinstance(image, (bytearray, bytes)):
               image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))

           self.image_sizes.append(image.size)

           # Normalize and resize images
           image = self.transform(image)

           # To handel case of png
           if image.shape[-1] == 4:
               image = image[:, :, :, :3]

           images.append(image.unsqueeze(0))

       return images

   def convert_to_result_dict(self, box_cls_lst, box_pred_lst, mask_pred_lst, image_sizes):
       """
       Arguments:
           box_cls_lst List(Tensor): tensor of shape (batch_size, num_queries, K).
               The tensor predicts the classification probability for each query.
           box_pred_lst List(Tensor): tensors of shape (batch_size, num_queries, 4).
               The tensor predicts 4-vector (x,y,w,h) box
               regression values for every queryx
           image_sizes (List[List]): the input image sizes
       Returns:
           results (List[Instances]): a list of #images elements.
       """
       # assert len(box_cls_lst) == len(image_sizes)

       # Apply NMS and softmax
       labels = []
       scores = []
       new_box_cls_lst = []
       new_box_pred_lst = []
       for box_cls, box_pred in zip(box_cls_lst, box_pred_lst):
           # For each box we assign the best class or the second best if the best on is `no_object`.
           score, label = box_cls.softmax(-1)[:, :-1].max(-1)

           # Select bounding box above score_thresh
           keep = score.cpu().detach().numpy() >= self.score_thresh
           box_cls = box_cls[keep]
           box_pred = box_pred[keep]
           label = label[keep]
           score = score[keep]

           keep = batched_nms(box_pred, score, label, self.test_nms_thresh)
           box_cls = box_cls[keep]
           box_pred = box_pred[keep]
           label = label[keep]
           score = score[keep]

           labels.append(label)
           scores.append(score)
           new_box_cls_lst.append(box_cls)
           new_box_pred_lst.append(box_pred)

       box_cls_lst = new_box_cls_lst
       box_pred_lst = new_box_pred_lst

       # Create detectron2 instance of object detection
       results = []
       for i, (scores_per_image, labels_per_image, box_pred_per_image, image_size) in enumerate(zip(
           scores, labels, box_pred_lst, self.image_sizes
       )):
           width, height = image_size
           result = Instances([height, width])


           result.pred_boxes = Boxes(box_cxcywh_to_xyxy(box_pred_per_image))
           result.pred_boxes.scale(scale_x=width, scale_y=height)
           result.scores = scores_per_image
           result.pred_classes = labels_per_image

           # if self.mask_on:
           #     mask = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(mask_pred[i].unsqueeze(0), size=image_size, mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
           #     mask = mask[0].sigmoid() > 0.5
           #     B, N, H, W = mask_pred.shape
           #     mask = BitMasks(mask.cpu()).crop_and_resize(result.pred_boxes.tensor.cpu(), 32)
           #     result.pred_masks = mask.unsqueeze(1).to(mask_pred[0].device)

           results.append(result)
       return results

   def inference(self, images):
       """ Predict the class of a text using a trained transformer model.
       """

       box_cls_lst = []
       box_pred_lst = []
       mask_pred_lst = []
       for image in images:

           output = dict(self.model(image))

           box_cls = output['logits'][0]
           box_pred = output['pred_boxes'][0]
           mask_pred = output.get("pred_masks", None) if self.mask_on else None
           if mask_pred is not None:
               mask_pred = mask_pred[0]

           box_cls_lst.append(box_cls)
           box_pred_lst.append(box_pred)
           mask_pred_lst.append(mask_pred)

       results = self.convert_to_result_dict(box_cls_lst, box_pred_lst, mask_pred_lst, self.image_sizes)

       return results

   def postprocess(self, results):
       processed_results = []
       for results_per_image, image_size in zip(results, self.image_sizes):
           width, height = image_size

           r = detector_postprocess(results_per_image, height, width)

           for box, label, prob in zip(
               [[float(d) for d in list(bbox)] for bbox in r.pred_boxes.tensor.cpu().detach().numpy()],
               [self.mapping[str(cs)] for cs in list(r.pred_classes.cpu().detach().numpy())],
               [float(d) for d in list(r.scores.cpu().detach().numpy())]
           ):
               processed_results.append({
                   'score': prob,
                   'label': label,
                   'box': {
                       'xmin': int(box[0]),
                       'ymin': int(box[1]),
                       'xmax': int(box[2]),
                       'ymax': int(box[3])
                   }
               })

       return processed_results
```

Here is my InferenceService

```
apiVersion: serving.kserve.io/v1beta1
kind: InferenceService
metadata:
  name: custom-model
  namespace: user1
spec:
  predictor:
    containers:
      - name: kserve-container
        image: <Dockerhub>/<Docker image >
        env:
          - name: "MODEL_NAME"
            value: "table_det"
          - name: "PROTOCOL"
            value: "v1"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8085
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 100
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8085
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          periodSeconds: 30
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
```

I have deployed the Inference service file with Docker image.
I got the services like

```
Inference service {true}
ksvc {true}
Revision {true]
route {true}
virtualservice {true}
```

All the services created by Kserve ,knative-serving and istio is created successfully without any error but i'm not able to establish the connection between the ingress of istio and the model.

Give me the best solution : thank you

I need solution and how the connection happens between the kserve and model deployed. I want to set perfect connection between the model and kserve

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the logs for your KServe service?  This looks like it could be an unhandled program exit, for example.

Comment: I didn't find any error is in the kserve

Comment: Hello guys, I have resolved this issue with simple technique. I'm going to explain now . We all install kserve, knative, istio, and cert-manager while integrating the system  istio-system to the local or kserve we follow the mtls enabled in a strict mode..                          example:   **`apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: user1
spec:
  mtls:
    mode:  STRICT` **    we have do disable it's better to avoid when don't use the dns and it's configuration